# Checking for iOS - Why is this variable undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

I'm trying to change how a page acts depending on which version of iOS the user is visiting on.

Below is what I have:

```
    function iOSversion() {
  if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {
    // supports iOS 2.0 and later: <http://bit.ly/TJjs1V>
    var v = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/);
    return [parseInt(v[1], 10), parseInt(v[2], 10), parseInt(v[3] || 0, 10)];
  }
}

var ver = iOSversion();

if (ver[0] >= 8) {
 alert("using iOS8");
} else if (ver[0] <= 7) {
 alert("using iOS7 or earlier");
}
```

I'm getting 'TypeError: ver is undefined'.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: Does your function return anything...? `console.log(ver)` before using

Comment: you must add another return in case the condition is not met.

Answer (score 2):

When `if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {` check fails your method returns nothing so it `ver` is `undefined`.

```
function iOSversion() {
  if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {
    // supports iOS 2.0 and later: <http://bit.ly/TJjs1V>
    var v = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/);
    return [parseInt(v[1], 10), parseInt(v[2], 10), parseInt(v[3] || 0, 10)];
  } else {
    return [];  //<-- return an empty array and it will not error. 
  }
}
```

OR check to see if version has a value before you use if.

```
var ver = iOSversion();
if (ver) { /* do it */ }
```

Comment: Oh okay, so it'll be happening because I'm testing on something that isn't iOS?

Comment: I do not know what you are testing on.

Comment: I have been testing on an iPad and get an error which results in it breaking. When I look at it in a browser window on desktop, it breaks but gives me the ver undefined issue. So maybe desktop browser only sees up until the ver undefined?